# How to fetch duplicate rows from the same table

Tags: duplicates

Assuming I have a table like:

| ID | valA | valB | valC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | aaaaa | NYC |
| 4 | 12 | bbbbb | NYC |
| 2 | 31 | ddddd | LA |
| 2 | 23 | eeeee | LA |
| 2 | 41 | fffff | NE |
| 3 | 23 | ggggg | JE |
| 3 | 44 | hhhhh | KA |

I want to compare rows to find those with certain data matching. In this case I want to identify rows with matching ID and valC. The contents of the valA and valB column are ignored.
So, it should find only those two rows:

| ID | valA | valB | valC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 31 | ddddd | LA |
| 2 | 23 | eeeee | LA |

I tried something with "count()" and "inner Join" but I didnt get the result what I am expecting.

I am pretty new on SQL so I would appreciate any tipps and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach, using analytic functions:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, valC) cnt
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT ID, valA, valB, valC
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I didnt't know about "with" and "partition by". Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach by filtering concatenated `id`, `valc` that are stored more than once:

```sql
SELECT 
*
FROM table_name
WHERE id||valc in
    (SELECT 
           id||valc
     FROM 
           TABLE_NAME
     GROUP BY (id_, valc)
     HAVING count(1) > 1);
```